# Javascript "global" variable issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml-parsing, global-variables

```
    var desc;
    $.ajax({
        url: "data/step2.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data){
            $(data).find('date').each(function(){
                var day = $(this).find('day').text();
                var date = $("#txtDate").datepicker("getDate");
                date = (date.getDate()+"-"+date.getMonth()+1+"-"+date.getFullYear());
                if (day==date){
                    $(this).find('availability').each(function(){
                        var prod = $(this).find('product').text();
                        var time = $(this).find('starttime').text();
                        if (prod==label){
                            desc="!";
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I'm having some issues accessing the `desc` variable... I want to manipulate it's value as you can see in `desc="!"`, but it returns undefined. Isn't there any way to make the variable global or something? or some other way to access it? ...
Oh, and all this code is inside a function.

Comment: $.ajax is async by default. Looks like you are trying to access `desc` before the ajax call completes.

Comment: First are you sure your code is run up to `desc="!"`?

Comment: You say "all code is inside a function..." *which* function?  Is it all inside the `success` function?

Comment: @techfoobar: but the `desc = "1"` is **INSIDE** the `success:` handler, so by definition the assignment wouldn't happen until after the ajax results come in anyways.

Comment: Yes, checked with console.log

Comment: @MarcB - Yes, the assignment is inside the success callback. But it looks like the OP's trying to read the value `desc` outside the `$.ajax(..)` before the success actually completes. Probably trying to return `desc` from the function all that code is in.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case the problem is not the scoping of the `desc` variable.  The `desc` variable you manipulate in the `success` callback is the same one declared before the ajax call.

The problem here is timing.  The `success` method doesn't execute at the same time the ajax call is made.  It executes some time later when the ajax call completes.  Only at that point is the value written to `desc`.  Any code which handles the `desc` value must be called from the point where the `desc` value is set

```
if (prod == labe) { 
  desc = "!";
  onDescChanged();
}
```

Comment: Oh, got it. Thank you! I'll try something else :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume your code is attempting something like:

```
function foo() {
    var desc;
    $.ajax({
        ....
        success: function() {
            ...
            desc = "!";
        }
    });
    return desc; // this will return undefined, as success() hasn't completed
}
```

To counter this, use a callback function as in JaredPar's answer.